# Is having explosions as a go-to solution considered bad table manners?

Tags: problem-players, social, starfinder

I am working on a Starfinder character who specializes in explosions, whose go-to solution is applying explosives to a problem till it ceases to be a problem. I am afraid I will be perceived as detrimental to the story, though.

Would making such a destructive character be considered disruptive and be frowned upon?

Comment: [Related(panels 7, 8, 9) view](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0696.html)

Comment: Just for the record, this character is Rico, from the Madagascar Penguins ("Kaboom KABOOM??").

Comment: It's possible to play an explosion-obsessed character without being disruptive. Depending on the tone of your game, Rather than Rico, consider something more like Vinny from *Atlantis, the Lost Empire*. Not everything needs to be blown up, but when it does, *you've got that covered.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### *Using* explosions as a go-to solution *could* be a problem…

…or it could be super cool. The only way you'll know is by checking with the people you're playing with, including the GM, the players and their PCs.

### Will this PC be detrimental to the story?

Your GM can provide the best answer to this question. Check with the GM before the campaign begins.

#### Will such a destructive character be considered disruptive and be frowned upon?

Your fellow players should answer this question. Ask them before the PC enters play how they would feel about this kind of character being part of the crew. If they're not keen on the idea, all is not lost: tone down your PC's personality and modify the PC's skill set to fit in.

Every table is unique, so keep checking as the game progresses. If the players appreciate your PC's direct solutions, forge on. If they tire of the monotony of his blow-it-up attitude, mix it up with other appropriate approaches: instead of lobbing flechette grenades at every opportunity, consider other approaches that use the skills of your fellow PCs. For example, collaborate with them to lay down a series of mines or charges connected by det cord - or even completely hang back during some situations.

Ask yourself, "Does this encounter need finesse?" And, if your PC hasn't advanced beyond blowing stuff up, sit out the situation or check with your crew before taking action to determine what would be most helpful.

A player who *dominates* encounters when other players want to participate takes away from the enjoyment of the whole table, so don't be that player, and, by all means, avoid [My Guy Syndrome](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it).

Comment: I can confirm this answer. I've had sci-fi/space campaigns (not Starfinder but other systems) that have been very successful as well as ones that have been killed by this type of character (did you know that spaceships bombing buildings from orbit does a *ton* of damage in Star Wars: Force and Destiny?) Absolutely a great answer, down to the last paragraphs